http://vault.centos.org returns 502 error
I have centos 7. After EOL, modified all the repos to vault.centos.org, as advised in:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1161816/mirrorlist-centos-org-no-longer-resolve
Until this morning everything worked fine.
Now tried to run yum install on some software and got the error:
http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 502 - Bad Gateway
Any advice ?

see notification here: https://vault.centos.org/

I do see vault.centog.org retrun: "This is NOT an updated tree for installing CentOS Linux : It is a snapshot of the older trees that have been removed from the main CentOS servers as new point releases are released.
This is provided for reference and to provide access to older archived versions, and we do not put security updates into the trees on this server.
Please see this link for active versions of CentOS Linux"

"RHEL 7 reaches End of Maintance on June 30, 2024. After June 30, 2024, there will be NO updates published for CentOS Linux 7."  (link: https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/#:~:text=RHEL%207%20reaches%20End%20of%20Maintance%20on%20June%2030%2C%202024.%20After%20June%2030%2C%202024%2C%20there%20will%20be%20no%20updates%20published%20for%20CentOS%20Linux%207. )

@Luuk it means that the code is not going to receive more updates, the code should be maintained in the vault servers. It looks an issue in the vault server

@Ainokila: I think I know English well enough to understand that the code is no longer there, because "out of support"..  You can find a mirror that still has it , like: https://mirror.cs.princeton.edu/pub/mirrors/centos/7.9.2009/

@Luuk the code is there. See https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/ , it has the same content with that mirror.

It seems like valut.centos.org origin is having some troubles at the moment, therefor 502 response..
You can try using one of external mirrors found in the list: https://vault.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/
Instead of replacing original mirror link with vault url, try replacing it with the one from the list, for example:
sed -i -e "s|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=https://mirror.nsc.liu.se/centos-store|g" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*


Seems they have resolved the problem with repository.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/archive.kernel.org\/centos-vault/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo

centos repo move to archive kernel and add path centos-vault

An example in a docker file:
FROM centos:7

# Set timezone Buenos Aires
ENV TIMEZONE America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TIMEZONE /etc/localtime && echo $TIMEZONE > /etc/timezone

RUN sed -i 's/mirror.centos.org/archive.kernel.org\/centos-vault/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
RUN sed -i s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
RUN sed -i s/^mirrorlist=http/#mirrorlist=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo


Be careful when formatting code. You had marked your Docker configuration as JavaScript, which instructs StackOverflow to treat it as client-executable, standalone code. It obviously isn’t. I’ve removed this, and improved the formatting of the CLI commands as well.
